# Error: unexpected symbol/input/string constant/numeric constant/SPECIAL in my code

Tags: r, r-faq

I received one of these errors.

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "<my code>"    
Error: unexpected input in "<my code>"
Error: unexpected string constant in "<my code>"  
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "<my code>"   
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "<my code>"         
Error: unexpected '<some punctuation>' in "<my code>" 
Error: unexpected '<reserved word>' in "<my code>"
```

**What does the error mean, and how can I fix it?**

Some simple examples that reproduce the errors, and common variants:

```
a a
## Error: unexpected symbol in "a a"
a\
## Error: unexpected input in "a\"
a""
## Error: unexpected string constant in "a"""
""1
## Error: unexpected numeric constant in """1"
%%
## Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%%"
,
## Error: unexpected ',' in ","
=
## Error: unexpected '=' in "="
)
## Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
else
## Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
```

Comment: They could head off quite a few dups tho. Nice addition to the FAQ, Richie.

Comment: While an extensive list of answers is nice, the "choice overload" problem may actually drive users away.  Any chance you could trim down to 10 or fewer links which cover 99% of the errors?

Comment: How about if everyone who reads this clicks through to a few links, and votes to close anything that looks low quality.  Once the rubbish has been gotten rid of, I'll reduce this list of links.

Comment: BTW, the links are ordered from oldest to newest in each category.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful this will be in practice, but I don't think it's a terrible idea. I _do_ think that the question would be a lot better without the massive list of links in it, though. (IMO)

Comment: I think the links might actually be better in the answer rather than the question. It's several screens full of scrolling before one gets to the answer.

Comment: OK, by popular request the monstrous list of links has been moved out of the way to answer.  Its main purpose was less to be useful than to point out that we have a big duplicate problem with this, so please do click through and mark some of these old, bad questions as dupes.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

These errors mean that the R code you are trying to run or source is not syntactically correct.  That is, you have a typo.

To fix the problem, read the error message carefully.  The code provided in the error message shows where R thinks that the problem is.  Find that line in your original code, and look for the typo.

---

**Prophylactic measures to prevent you getting the error again**

The best way to avoid syntactic errors is to write stylish code.  That way, when you mistype things, the problem will be easier to spot.  There are many R style guides linked from the [SO R tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) page.  You can also use the `formatR` package to automatically format your code into something more readable.  In RStudio, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> will reformat your code.

Consider using an IDE or text editor that highlights matching parentheses and braces, and shows strings and numbers in different colours.

---

**Common syntactic mistakes that generate these errors**

**Mismatched parentheses, braces or brackets**

If you have nested parentheses, braces or brackets it is very easy to close them one too many or too few times.

```
{}}
## Error: unexpected '}' in "{}}"
{{}} # OK
```

---

**Missing** `*` **when doing multiplication**

This is a common mistake by mathematicians.

```
5x
Error: unexpected symbol in "5x"
5*x # OK
```

---

**Not wrapping if, for, or return values in parentheses**

This is a common mistake by MATLAB users.  In R, `if`, `for`, `return`, etc., are functions, so you need to wrap their contents in parentheses.

```
if x > 0 {}
## Error: unexpected symbol in "if x"
if(x > 0) {} # OK
```

---

**Not using multiple lines for code**

Trying to write multiple expressions on a single line, without separating them by semicolons causes R to fail, as well as making your code harder to read.

```
x + 2 y * 3
## Error: unexpected symbol in "x + 2 y"
x + 2; y * 3 # OK
```

---

**`else` starting on a new line**

In an `if`-`else` statement, the keyword `else` must appear on the same line as the end of the `if` block.

```
if(TRUE) 1
else 2
## Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"    
if(TRUE) 1 else 2 # OK
if(TRUE) 
{
  1
} else            # also OK
{
  2
}
```

---

**`=` instead of `==`**

`=` is used for assignment and giving values to function arguments.  `==` tests two values for equality.

```
if(x = 0) {}
## Error: unexpected '=' in "if(x ="    
if(x == 0) {} # OK
```

---

**Missing commas between arguments**

When calling a function, each argument must be separated by a comma.

```
c(1 2)
## Error: unexpected numeric constant in "c(1 2"
c(1, 2) # OK
```

---

**Not quoting file paths**

File paths are just strings.  They need to be wrapped in double or single quotes.

```
path.expand(~)
## Error: unexpected ')' in "path.expand(~)"
path.expand("~") # OK
```

---

**Quotes inside strings**

This is a common problem when trying to pass quoted values to the shell via `system`, or creating quoted `xPath` or `sql` queries.

Double quotes inside a double quoted string need to be escaped.  Likewise, single quotes inside a single quoted string need to be escaped. Alternatively, you can use single quotes inside a double quoted string without escaping, and vice versa.

```
"x"y"
## Error: unexpected symbol in ""x"y"   
"x\"y" # OK
'x"y'  # OK
```

---

**Using curly quotes**

So-called "smart" quotes are not so smart for R programming.

```
path.expand(“~”)
## Error: unexpected input in "path.expand(“"    
path.expand("~") # OK
```

---

**Using non-standard variable names without backquotes**

[`?make.names`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/make.names) describes what constitutes a valid variable name.  If you create a non-valid variable name (using `assign`, perhaps), then you need to access it with backquotes,

```
assign("x y", 0)
x y
## Error: unexpected symbol in "x y"
`x y` # OK
```

This also applies to column names in data frames created with `check.names = FALSE`.

```
dfr <- data.frame("x y" = 1:5, check.names = FALSE)
dfr$x y
## Error: unexpected symbol in "dfr$x y"
dfr[,"x y"] # OK
dfr$`x y`   # also OK
```

It also applies when passing operators and other special values to functions.  For example, looking up help on `%in%`.

```
?%in%
## Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "?%in%"
?`%in%` # OK
```

---

**Sourcing non-R code**

The `source` function runs R code from a file.  It will break if you try to use it to read in your data.  Probably you want [`read.table`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/read.table).

```
source(textConnection("x y"))
## Error in source(textConnection("x y")) : 
##   textConnection("x y"):1:3: unexpected symbol
## 1: x y
##       ^
```

---

**Corrupted RStudio desktop file**

RStudio users [have reported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24105935/134830) erroneous source errors due to a corrupted  `.rstudio-desktop` file.  These reports only occurred around March 2014, so it is possibly an issue with a specific version of the IDE.  RStudio can be reset using [the instructions](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-s-State) on the support page.

---

**Using expression without paste in mathematical plot annotations**

When trying to create mathematical labels or titles in plots, the expression created must be a syntactically valid mathematical expression as described on the [`?plotmath`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/grDevices/plotmath) page.  Otherwise the contents should be contained inside a call to paste.

```
plot(rnorm(10), ylab = expression(alpha ^ *)))
## Error: unexpected '*' in "plot(rnorm(10), ylab = expression(alpha ^ *"
plot(rnorm(10), ylab = expression(paste(alpha ^ phantom(0), "*"))) # OK
```

Comment: A really common way to get this is when you copy code. For example, copying code from R bloggers often has the "" formatted to non-identical speech marks, or space characters that look like a space, but aren't.  Similar things happen when copying from google quick link, where Google (not so) helpfully puts spaces into variable names (e.g. `my.var` becomes `my. var`.

Answer (score 5):

For me the error was:

```
Error: unexpected input in "�"
```

and the fix was opening the script in a hex editor and removing the first 3 characters from the file. The file was starting with an UTF-8 BOM and it seems that Rscript can't read that.

EDIT: OP requested an example. Here it goes.

```
➜  ~ cat a.R
cat('hello world\n')
➜  ~ xxd a.R
00000000: efbb bf63 6174 2827 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f  ...cat('hello wo
00000010: 726c 645c 6e27 290a                      rld\n').
➜  ~ R -f a.R        

R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> cat('hello world\n')
Error: unexpected input in "�"
Execution halted
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a reproducible example. Also can you set the file encoding as a solution?

Comment: Not sure how I would provide a reproducible example. Paste a base64-encoded file here so that the special characters aren't lost? Paste a hex dump?

Comment: How about: using `cat()` to create a file with the offending content, then calling `Rscript` via `system()`. Or maybe the `littler` package.

Answer (score 3):

If you are copy-pasting code into R, it sometimes won't accept some special characters such as "~" and will appear instead as a "�". So if a certain character is giving an error, make sure to use your keyboard to enter the character, or find another website to copy-paste from if that doesn't work.