# What is the "unexpected symbol" in my while statement?

Tags: r

I am having trouble with what seems to be a very basic R statement:

```
while (count < 10) { print(count) count <- count + 1}
Error: unexpected symbol in "while (count < 10) { print(count) count"
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Perhaps you need `;`  `while (count < 10) { print(count); count <- count + 1}`

Comment: Yes that seemed to work just fine! Thank you for your input. As a matter of best practice, do you think it would be to my benefit to create new lines in between the statements?

Comment: Yes. You should definitely choose and stick to a style. I adhere (mostly) to [Google's R Style Guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml). Semicolons (like pie charts) are evil.

Comment: Yes, new statements on new lines.  And indentation too. It makes code more readable for others and will make debugging easier for you

Comment: Thanks all for the feedback. I really appreciate it. I'm such a rookie!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: unexpected symbol/input/string constant/numeric constant/SPECIAL in my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889234/error-unexpected-symbol-input-string-constant-numeric-constant-special-in-my-co)

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would put the "more than simple call" on multiple lines as follows:

```
while (count < 10) { 
    print(count) 
    count <- count + 1
}
```

This makes what you're doing clearer and avoids problems like you're getting.

Comment: Thank you for the example, Tyler.