# Trying to run glmulti with quasipoisson

Tags: r, glm

I have tried running the following **equation**:

```
modruns2 <- glmulti(SRI ~ TVIS + SNH3000 + BU1000 + TBE250 + TS3000 + TAB3000 +
                    PELHL1000 + SR250 + SW250, data = data1, family = quasipoisson,
                    glmulti-cvalue = 6.219132, level =1, maxsize = 4, crit = qaicc)
```

And it comes up with the **error**:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "modruns2 <- glmulti(SRI ~ TVIS + SNH3000 + BU1000 + TBE250 + 

TS3000 + TAB3000 + PELHL1000 + SR250 + SW250, data = data1, family = quasipoisson, glmulti-

cvalue ="
```

I have been trying to follow http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmulti/glmulti.pdf  &  http://vcalcagnoresearch.wordpress.com/package-glmulti/

But it seems I may be specifying the c-hat incorrectly.

Any help?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a `glmulti-cvalue` parameter in the documentation. However, the error is weird. Try `?glmulti-cvalue` and maybe try that as a function if it exists.

Comment: add this `setOption(“glmulti-value”=6.219132)` before your code and then run your `glmulti` function without the `glmulti-cvalue` parameter.

Comment: I have tried running that before                                     > setOption(“glmulti-value”=6.219132)
Error: unexpected input in "setOption(“"

Comment: Hmmm I don't know what else it might be then I m afraid... I read that from the second link you provided. If I where you I 'd try to find that variable in the source code and see if it is there, and how it is calculated. Then maybe try and change it in the code...

Comment: read this one too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889234/error-unexpected-symbol-input-string-constant-numeric-constant-special-in-my-co

Comment: This looks like a syntax error.

Comment: yep. remove the hyphen `'-'` and try again. I think that's causing the issue. it probably reads it as minus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package named `R.utils`.
What LyzandeR suggests was correct. But instead of

```
setOption('glmulti-cvalue'=6.219132)
```

use

```
setOption('glmulti-cvalue',6.219132)
```

I had the same issue, and I found answer in an example on [this page](http://statistics.unl.edu/faculty/bilder/categorical/Chapter5/AlcoholDetailed.R).