# R giving error for else statement

Tags: r

I have the following code/pseudocode:

```
    if (condition A)
        {
          if(condition B)
             {
               print("Yes")
             }
          else 
            {
               print("No")
            }

         }
   else
       {
         print("Maybe")
       }
```

Why does R say the last  `else`  is an unexpected token?

Comment: Please add a reproducible example so that it is easy to help you. Moreover, that thing is most likely because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889234/error-unexpected-symbol-input-string-constant-numeric-constant-special-in-my-co

Comment: Put it on the same line as the previous closing brace, as in `} else {` instead of `}\n else`. (It's a parser thing, where the newline after the `}` causes it to infer that it should expect a "new/fresh" command, not a command-continuance like `else`.)

Comment: ... though I like that link that @RonakShah provided, citing *Prophylactic measures to prevent you getting the error again*. Nice (and a good read for all aspiring programmers in R)!

Comment: all of your questions have answers, and you have checked _one_ of them. also please follow this style guide https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

```
if (1 > 2){
  print("Yes")
}  # this if statement ends here, then the else throws an error
else {
  print("No")
}
```

> Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"

With:

```
if (1 > 2){
  print("Yes")
} else {
  print("No")
}

[1] "No"
```

You have to begin your `else` statement on the same line, otherwise R reads it as two distinct statements, rather than all part of one `if` statement.