# Getting unexpected input error in R expression

Tags: r

I'm trying to run this code to stretch the axes after creating a matrix based on calculated Euclidean distances:

```
ds_newA <- sqrt((new[1] -A[1]ˆ2 + (3*(new[2]-A[2]))ˆ2)
```

However, I'm getting an input error in the R console:

```
Error: unexpected input in "ds_newA <- sqrt((new[1] -A[1])ˆ"
Error: unexpected input in "ds_newB <- sqrt((new[1] -B[1])ˆ"
```

How should the code for formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed in the SO thread [Error: unexpected symbol/input/string constant/numeric constant/SPECIAL in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889234/error-unexpected-symbol-input-string-constant-numeric-constant-special-in-my-co) :

> These errors mean that the R code you are trying to run or source is not syntactically correct. That is, you have a typo.
>
> To fix the problem, read the error message carefully. The code provided in the error message shows where R thinks that the problem is. Find that line in your original code, and look for the typo.

Most probably, here this is due to the symbol `ˆ` you are using, which is not the appropriate one for an exponent `^`:

```
# correct symbol ^:
> 2^2
[1] 4

# wrong symbol you seem to use ˆ :
> 2ˆ2
Error: unexpected input in "2ˆ"
```

Change it to the correct one `^` and you will be fine.